# Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : latitude < -90 _- getting this error in R

Tags: r

```r
file_data_frame$sg_long <- 103.843061
file_data_frame$sg_lat <- 1.276105
distGeo(file_data_frame[,c("LONGITUDE","LATITUDE")],
        file_data_frame[,c("sg_long","sg_lat")])/1609.35
```

some data from the data frame file_data_frame with negative values are as below,

[image: data with negative latitude value]

It is working fine with -90 to 90 latitude value. Please help.

Comment: Hi Ayan. The problem seems to be with your data. How can you have a latitude of less than -90 degrees? You can't define a point South of the South Pole.Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It looks as though you have switched the column labels.  As @AllanCameron said, those values don't make sense as latitudes, but if the column labels are switched, the first 3 are coastal North American locations.  I didn't check the others.